# Getting content by class name javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the content inside of a  by the class name but i get undefined when i run the script... what am i doing wrong?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<td class="a-size-base">B000FNFSPY</td>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("a-size-base").innerText;
    document.write(x)
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
   <div class="a-size-base">B000FNFSPY</div>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 <script>
   function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("a-size-base")[0].innerText;
    document.write(x)
   }
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When the browser compiles with `td` then since `table` tag is not used and hence it renders it as it is and the `td` tag is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You misused `<td>` tag, it has to be put inside a table.
Or it will not be rendered into DOM with webkit or most browsers.

Tested in Chrome. See, `<td>` is not there.

And `getElementsByTagName` returns an array. But you went wrong in the first step, so it's not even get here yet.

[image]

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("a-size-base");
    document.write(x);
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<td class="a-size-base">B000FNFSPY</td>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="a-size-base">B000FNFSPY</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("a-size-base");
    document.write(x[0].innerHTML)
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByClassName method returns an array-like collection of elements. You should loop through the items to access their innerText.